# Maximum threads per block vs shared memory size

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, gpu-shared-memory

Is there any relation between the *size of the shared memory* and the *maximum number of threads per block*?. In my case I use *Max threads per block = 512*, my program makes use of all the threads and it uses considerable amount of shared memory.

Each thread has to do a particular task repeatedly. For example my kernel might look like,

```
int threadsPerBlock = (blockDim.x * blockDim.y * blockDim.z);
int bId = (blockIdx.x * gridDim.y * gridDim.z) + (blockIdx.y * gridDim.z) + blockIdx.z;
for(j = 0; j <= N; j++) {
    tId = threadIdx.x + (j * threadsPerBlock);
    uniqueTid = bId*blockDim.x + tId;
    curand_init(uniqueTid, 0, 0, &seedValue);
    randomP = (float) curand_uniform( &seedValue );
    if(randomP <= input_value) 
         /* Some task */
    else
         /* Some other task */
}
```

But my threads are not going into next iteration *(say `j` = 2)*. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: How does your program uses the "considerable amount of shared memory"? It's not clear how the code explains your question.

Answer (score 2):

You have to distinct between `shared memory` and `global memory`. The former is always per block. The latter refers to the off-chip memory that is available on the GPU.

So generally speaking, there is a kind of relation when it comes to threads, i.e. when having more threads per block, the maximum amount of shared memory stays the same.

Also refer to e.g. [Using Shared Memory in CUDA C/C++](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/using-shared-memory-cuda-cc/).

Comment: No my question is say i have used all of the shared memory, Does that mean that i can't launch 512 threads ? Any relations between them.

Comment: You can launch as much threads as are allowed per block. This does not affect the maximum usable shared memory, which is set by the design of the GPU itself.

Answer (score 2):

There is **no immediate relationship** between the maximum number of threads per block and the size of the shared memory (not 'device memory' - they're not the same thing).

However, there is an **indirect relationship**, in that with different [Compute Capabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA#Version_features_and_specifications), both these numbers change:

| Compute Capability | 1.x | 2.x - 3.x |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Threads per block | 512 | 1024 |
| Max shared memory (per block) | 16KB | 48KB |

as one of them has increased with newer CUDA devices, so has the other.

Finally, there is a block-level resource which is affected, used up, by the launching of more threads: The Register File. There is a single register file which all block threads share, and the constraint is

> ThreadsPerBlock x RegistersPerThread <= RegisterFileSize

It is not trivial to determine how many registers your kernel code is using; but as a rule of thumb, if you use "a lot" of local variables, function call parameters etc., you might hit the above limit, and will not be able to schedule as many threads.

Comment: How is it "not trivial" to determine the number of registers a kernel uses? The compiler will print out the per thread resource usage for you and there is a spreadsheet provided in every version of the toolkit that allows the exact resource usage for a given kernel launch.

Comment: @talonmies: 'Not trivial' as in - you need the compiler's help for it; it takes some experience to be able to estimate this well merely by looking at the code.

Comment: @einpoklum Can you explain or throw some pointers on how to determine the currently active registers inside kernel?

Comment: @Bala: Use NVIDIA's NSight tool, it shows you the register usage. You can also have a look at the PTX code (i.e. use the nvcc switch for leaving intermediary kernel ptx files intact).